# controller.rb - server not opening site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently working through the 'Agile Web Development with Rails 4' text book, trying to learn something (if possible).

I'm around a third of the way through building a very simple online bookstore and testing it using the Rails Server.

I turned the server on and have tried to access my application but there's a problem with the store_controller.rb file.

The web page says: `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

The code of the file is the following:

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)
  end
end
```

Thank you for your time and thoughts!

Index.html.erb

```
<% if notice %>
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<h1> Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>
<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <% cache ['entry', product] do %>
      <div class="entry">
        <%=image_tag(product.image_url) %>
        <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
        <div class="price_line">
          <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
          <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Post your full error stack.

Comment: Could you show the `index.html.erb` for this controller please.

Comment: Just added the index.html.erb code above, thanks guys!

Comment: add <%end%> for each of the loops in your index file

Comment: Having fixed the indentation in your code I can't see any missing `end`; could you post the full error with the stacktrace please.  It's possible though that you have some control characters we can't see in the paste here so you should check that.

Comment: I'm a little unsure what you mean by stack trace. I'm guessing you mean from the error page that shows up in the browser? If so, app/controllers/store_controller.rb:3:in `index'
That's the application trace. Do you want the full trace?

Comment: No, that's fine.  I don't get it though - even before I edited the format of your controller there were two `end` statements - I didn't add them, just put your controller in a code block and indented it.  Copying exactly what you originally posted for the controller into a test file and running `ruby -c test.rb` shows `Syntax OK`.  Line 3 is `@products = Product.order(:title)` right?  That can't be the end of the file - there must be some unprintable control characters on each of the end statements that is stopping them from being picked up.  Bizarre!

Comment: This is very strange because I've followed the book word for word and tried to keep it simple since I don't have a clue what's what yet. Line 3 is exactly as you've typed it out @products = Product.order(:title)

Comment: What do you recommend I do, is there anything I can do to get the application back working?

Comment: since the error message, as you said, is coming from `store_controller.rb file`, copy and paste the entire store controller (top to bottom), I bet there is `end` missing somewhere.

Comment: Wali I have already included that code above, in my original question post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys,

I found the problem. It was driving me crazy.

I messed around with the store_controller.rb file and kept reloading the browser. Then the errors were pointing me around to other files to sort out.

To cut a long story short, I was pointed to the product.rb file in the Models folder. I added an extra end and it all worked perfectly well from there I'm glad to announce.

Here's the code if you're interested:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items

    before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item

validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
validates :title, uniqueness: true
validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
with:   %r{\.(gif|jpg|png) \Z}i,
message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
}

def self.latest
Product.order(:updated_at).last

private

# ensure that there are no line items referencing this product
def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
    if line_items.empty
        return true
    else
    errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
    return false
    end
    end
    end
end
```